# Looping through results from MYSQL query and inserting into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'll try asking this question again. Hopefully making more sense this time!

I have an user editable cell on my webpage. I want to connect to MYSQL database and search a field for the  text input into this cell, for each result found, I want to add a new row to my table. I know how to connect to the databases and I know how to create a query over html. What I don't know and hoping for some guidance, is the mechanism for looping through each result and using a variable to complete the query!

My code for adding a row

```
<script>
function getsearchresults()
{
var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var row=table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML= Variable1heremaybe?;
cell2.innerHTML="Variable2heremaybe?;
cell3.innerHTML="Variable3heremaybe?;
cell4.innerHTML="Variable4heremaybe?;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table style="margin-top:350px; margin-left:25px;" id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>column1 <div style="width: 100px"> </div></td>
    <td>column2 <div style="width: 100px" > </div></td>
    <td>column3 <div style="width: 100px" > </div></td>
    <td>column4 <div style="width: 100px" > </div></td>

</table>
```

Query search code

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("bla","blabla","blablabla","blablabla");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

SELECT `Table1`.`Column1`
FROM Table1
WHERE (`Table1`.`Column1` Variableheremayb?)
ORDER BY `Table1`.`Column1` ASC
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:
Here I am assuming that you have already successfully connected to database

```
//first execute the query 

$result = mysqli_query("Your query");

//then fetch the result of each row using a loop

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  //here you can display the data or store it in a variable or anything else you want
  // for example you want to display it inside div tag.
   echo "<div>".$row["column1"]."</div>";
   echo "<div>".$row["column2"]."</div>";
   //and so on

}
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: thank you! However I can't seem to get a new row to add to the table, whilst within the while statement, and therefor obviously can't add the result. I'm not familiar with the .$row["column1"], is this suppose to populate a new row within 'mytable' with data from column1 of our active result?. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp) this is the affect I'm looking for, but with each result from our query!

Comment: are you familiar with ajax

Comment: no :( haha, a bit of a noob I'm affraid!. I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: if i am not wrong you want row to be added to the existing html table without refreshing the page when hit on the search button right? if so then it need to be done with ajax so you need learn it first to do it as such and if get stuck after that you can always come back to stackflow for help.

Comment: I appreciate your help, one last question before I go away and learn ajex properly!. This may seem naive, but the example I sent doesn't seem to refresh the page, just uses the var cell1=row.insertCell(0); then populates each cell directly using cell1.innerHTML="New";. Is there noway I can pass a variable in?, perhaps use a counter to increment through the results?

Comment: sure you can pass a variable if you are getting during page load but in your case your requirement will not be satisfied as you need to retrieve the data from database based on search input on that page at same time you want to add a new html table row with that retrieved data without refreshing the page which is only possible with ajax. Once you learn it, it will be clear to you what i am trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest to name your row cells in HTML as a same name `cell[]`. They will be posted as an array which is much easier to loop it.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell[]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Server side part:

```
<?php

// Connect to MySQL
...

// Validate your form inputs
...
$cells = yourInputFilter($_POST['cell']);
...

// Build query
$cellSql = implode(',', $cells);

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE column1 IN ($cellSql)
        ORDER BY column1";
```